# Is there a solution to custom-obfuscated files dissapearing from 1.8.8.jar?

Tags: java, client, minecraft

I'm creating a custom hacked client for minecraft v1.8.8, and the custom-hack files that I have re-obfuscated keep getting deleted on-launch.

I have already tried re-adding the correct files into the .jar after running the Client, but it still was deleted even after everything.

I expected all the files to be working normally and kept inside the JAR, but when I launch minecraft ( set onto the hacked client's version ), the .jar gets deleted and put back into the folder, but with missing files. There is no error. Just lack of expected files inside compiled client.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Minecraft launcher check the files of the game when you launch it and if they are differents from the files on their server, it redownload them.

You can avoid that by deleting the "downloads" section at the begining of the file 1.8.8.json in the same folder of the 1.8.8.jar.

This section looks like that, if the json is not fomatted you can use a json formatter tool.

```
   "downloads":{
  "client":{
     "sha1":"3870888a6c3d349d3771a3e9d16c9bf5e076b908",
     "size":8461484,
     "url":"https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/3870888a6c3d349d3771a3e9d16c9bf5e076b908/client.jar"
  },
  "server":{
     "sha1":"b58b2ceb36e01bcd8dbf49c8fb66c55a9f0676cd",
     "size":8320755,
     "url":"https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/b58b2ceb36e01bcd8dbf49c8fb66c55a9f0676cd/server.jar"
  },
  "windows_server":{
     "sha1":"5143618265b8a2d1d28bcadf206b7327738c2670",
     "size":8714995,
     "url":"https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/5143618265b8a2d1d28bcadf206b7327738c2670/windows_server.exe"
  }
```

}